# Why this script doesn't run after the first line

Tags: python-3.x

```
tweak = int(input("Input an integer"))
def collatz(number):
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            return int(number)
        elif number % 2 != 0:
            return int((3 * number) + 1)
    print(number)

collatz(tweak)
```

Comment: Can you explain better what is not working? What is the error code? When I paste it into Jupyter it works.

Comment: It's working for me in `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Are you telling that your `number` is not getting printed.?

Comment: You might be using Sublime Text which doesn't support console input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement a Collatz conjecture script, then your first `if` is wrong - you should divide the number by 2. Also, your `return` causes the function to end, so you get only one while loop, doesn't matter what happens inside - so you basically return the number you inputed or that number * 3 + 1.
Here is the correct code with slight modifications:

```
tweak = int(input("Input an integer"))
def collatz(number):
    steps = 0
    num = number
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number / 2
        else:
            number = int(3 * number + 1)
        steps +=1
    print("Reached 1 in {} iterations for number {}.".format(steps, num))

collatz(tweak)
```

You also don't need the `elif`, because number can only be dividable by 2 or not.

Example outputs:

```
collatz(22)
collatz(55)
collatz(234)

Reached 1 in 15 iterations for number 22.
Reached 1 in 112 iterations for number 55.
Reached 1 in 21 iterations for number 234.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your returning values in **if** and **else** so it wont print beyond..

instead assign it in variable and do print..

```
tweak = input("Input an integer")
def collatz(number):
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            return int(number)
        elif number % 2 != 0:
            return int((3 * number) + 1)
    print number  # this wont work.. your returned already
print "output:%s"%collatz(tweak)
```

**output:**

```
me@dev-007:~/Desktop$ python test.py 
Input an integer10
number 10
output:10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has only code, but I think this is what you might be looking for:

```
def collatz(tweak):
    while tweak != 1:
        if tweak % 2 == 0:
            return int(tweak)
        elif tweak % 2 != 0:
            return int((3 * tweak) + 1)
     print(tweak)
tweak = int(input("Input an integer:"))
result = collatz(tweak)
print(result)
```